# Name of R. Silverberg SF Short Story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robert-silverberg

I'm looking for the name of a Silverberg short story that had a woman (U.S. President, I think) making a speech upon return from a disastrous space mission.  Her husband kept interrupting her.

Answer (score 6):

It isn’t by Silverberg but your description matches the short story “[Inaugural](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51657)” by Barry N. Malzberg and Bill Pronzini so well that I think it must be the story you are remembering even though it has a different author.  A web search states that it was published in “Galaxy Science Fiction”, November 1976 and collected in "[100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?43)" edited by Isaac Asimov.

This is a short story (only 3 pages long).  The entire story takes the form of the inaugural address given by Carol.  She and her (now) husband George have just returned from a space mission, and been voted into office.  She is to be president, he is to be vice president.  Although we hear only her voice it is clear that he keeps interrupting her.  All does not appear to be well on Earth...